# How to get Random Value in c++ with SDL game

Tags: c++, random, sdl

I'm programming a game; I have an NPC that can move around the area, but there is a problem: they all go for the same direction because of the random value

These are the random functions:

```
int MoveObjects::GetRandomDirectionToMove()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        x = rand() % 4 + 1;
    return x;
}

int MoveObjects::GetRandomStepsToMove()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        x = rand() % 80 + 50;
    return x;
}

int MoveObjects::GetRandomTimeToStand()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        x = rand() % 20 + 10;
    return x;
}
```

and this is in the main

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    npc[i].MoveAround(area);
```

In this case there are 2 NPC but even if I try 50 NPC, all go to the same:
direction,steps,time to stand.

How i can get different values ?

I tried to read any guide or any question about random in this website but nothing not work.
i tried also put the srand in different locations and still all the NPC go same directions.
and maybe there is SDL function to get random value ?

One more thing about the for: if I remove the `for i` get the same value all the time.
that mean, all go same direction 1 direction

full movearound code:

```
int frame = GetFrameCount();
frame++;
SetFrameCount(frame);

static int current_step = 0;
static int current_direction = 0;
static int current_wait = 0;

if(!current_step) {
    current_step = GetRandomStepsToMove();
    current_direction = GetRandomDirectionToMove();
    current_wait = GetRandomTimeToStand();
}

if(!current_wait) {
    if(current_direction == 1)
        MoveUp(area);
    else if(current_direction == 2)
        MoveDown(area);
    else if(current_direction == 3)
        MoveRight(area);
    else if(current_direction == 4)
        MoveLeft(area);

    current_step--;
    if(current_step < 0) current_step = 0;
}

current_wait--;
if(current_wait < 0) current_wait = 0;
```

Comment: It's me or you loop are useless ?

Comment: Please add the code for the `MoveAround` method.

Also, are you getting any warnings or error messages when you try to compile?

Comment: 0 errors i added the full code

Comment: Then where is `MoveAround(area)` defined?!? (Also, you need to add the method header and inclusion directives you are using to the main method code.)

Comment: MoveAround is funcion of NPC object. i edit and add this function i tried to print and i still see the same value in the random.

Comment: Please post your test code.

Comment: Come on! You __need to post the method headers__, and __any and all namespace or import directives__.

Comment: i think i see what the problem is . like i thgout it snot about the srand. i think the static values have to be each object

Comment: Nope, as long as they are using the same global random function, they will get different numbers.

Comment: Also, where you are checking the `current_direction`, you should be using a `switch` statement.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Move[Direction]` methods you are calling actually do what you want them to do? You should test that; its possible that when you copied them, you didn't save the changes you made to make them move in different directions, and they all just move the character in the same direction.

Comment: Basically, you need to go through your code, and individually test every single method to make sure that it is working correctly, and exactly the way you think it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables current_step, current_direction, and current_wait should not be declared static. Declaring them static tells the compiler that those three values should be shared between all calls to your move around method. The result is the first time you generate random values for them, but for each successive call no new random values are generated because they've already been assigned.

Comment: Not so surprising, but the error was again in code that initially wasn't posted. People, if you need help, create a **small** program with the same problem. If the problem goes away, great, you just found the solution to your problem yourself.

Comment: @MSalters Although there were also problems with the code he did post, too. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are reseeding the RNG in each call.

**Remove the lines that go `srand ( time(NULL) );` from all the methods, and they will work as expected.**

To make the code better, I would recommend inserting `srand(time(NULL );` at the beginning of your *main* method (not the methods for getting randoms), once you have finished exterminating most of the bugs.

According to the c++ standard, you are not actually required to call `srand` in order to generate the values; calls to `rand` will behave as if you had called `srand(1)` at the start of the program.

---

Additionally, your randoming code is really much more complicated than it needs to be, and I will explain why:

In the method that goes

```
int MoveObjects::GetRandomDirectionToMove() {
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        x = rand() % 4 + 1;
    return x;
}
```

You are, for some reason, drawing five random numbers, but you are using only the last one. This is a waste, and you can do just fine by using only the first number drawn. Implementing it as

```
int MoveObjects::GetRandomDirectionToMove() {
    return rand() % 4 + 1;
}
```

would return results just as random, just as unpredictable, and five times faster.

Comment: And you need to use `srand ( time(NULL) );` once before calling `rand()`.

Comment: @vbmaster not nessisarily; you can actually call `srand` with any seed you want, and while you are still developing, it is usually a good idea to use a constant seed so you are able to predict the outcomes for testing purposes (so you can force possible edge cases and flush out the bugs).

Comment: What _exactly_ did you try?\

Comment: thats more 1 problem.. if i remove the for. i get exactly the same value any time

Comment: No. You did not pay attention. __The fix is to stop reseeding.__ Ditching the for loops just makes the program better, not fixes the problem.

Comment: @vbmaster I just checked, and according to the c++ standard, you do not need to call `srand` at all.

Comment: even of i dont call srand its not work. i told you "remove srand" is response to the quistions here about random. but here remove srand not helping

Comment: @RefaelOknin This next problem is inside your `npc[i].MoveAround(area)` method. Please edit your question and add the code for that method. If you need proof, try adding a line that prints out the random value to each method, so you can confirm that calls to `rand()` are generating random numbers. (Optins include `cout << x` and `println(x)`)

Comment: OK.. So it means at initialization time the RNG is automatically seeded?

Comment: @vbmaster Yes; you can think of it as if there were an implicit  `srand(1)` call at the beginning of the main method, and any other `srand` call just replaces the seed value.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `srand ( time(NULL) );` you are seeding the same value.

Call `srand ( time(NULL) );` once at the beginning of your application and it should solve your problem.

Comment: thank for the answer but i try this already. i told you itry to remove and i try alot of position of srand.. nothing help.